# Running a Chef guard block as a different user

Tags: chef-infra

I want to have a Chef guard block, and I want to run that block as a specific user.

I know how to run a shell command in a guard as a user, since that's covered in the documentation:

```
not_if 'grep adam /etc/passwd', :user => 'adam'
```

I want to use a guard block instead so I can do some more complex operations, and I want to run the code as the postgres user. For example:

```
only_if do
  c = PGconn.connect(user: 'postgres', dbname: 'postgres')
  # do some other stuff with the postgres connection
end
```

How do I assign the `user` or other attributes here?

Answer (score 0):

Code blocks aren't run as a user per se, they are just run by Ruby as whatever user Ruby happens to be running as. In this case case you probably want to shell out to `psql` and change the user as per normal for a subprocess.